# Outlook HTML editor is applying double border lines when I type hyphen

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I often use `---` in Outlook e-mails to draw a horizontal line. This allows me to put a passage of quoted text inside a border, like this

[image]

What I'm sometimes seeing though, is that when I use `---` on the line above a passage of text, there are 2 border lines

[image]

The Auto-Format option dialog only has the ability to toggle Border Lines on or off, not how/why/when to use double-lines.

Does anybody know why, in some cases, the HTML editor decides to use 2 border lines instead of 1?

Comment: Probably a trick of microsoft to make everyone go back to their horrible RTF format and the dreaded winmail.dat ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you see is the Outlook program, not an add-in.

I see this all the time.

I type four or five characters, keep typing and Outlook cannot interpret and does not change.

Normally I can just go back and delete the space and I have what I want.

The line I created can be used elsewhere in the email if need be. I do this as well.

This is a workaround but is painless.

Answer (score 1):

According to your description, I have done a lot of test on my Outlook 365 and found that the double border will appear when I typed "---" between two existing border. If i add "---" one by one from top to bottom, there will be no double border. If this is also your case, please add it one by one from top to bottom in order to avoid this situation.
[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer.